# Response does not match challenge, expected value = '1480587314'

Tags: php, html, facebook

I am trying to make one web app for facebook. I have created file index.php (just for primary testing) and entered URL of site to canvas callback URL. (Where I have registered for app. on http://developers.facebook.com ). Currently I am getting below error when I am testing the URL :

```
The request sent to your callback URL failed with the following error: 
Response does not match challenge, expected value = '1984864235',        received='<!DOCTYPE html> <htm...'
Request URL:
http://akworldweb.com/?hub.mode=subscribe&hub.challenge=1984864235
```

Below is the sample PHP file :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<h1>My first PHP page</h1>
<?php
echo "Hello World!";
?>

</body>
</html>
```

Can you please tell me whats wrong I am doing. I am all new to this. Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your sample PHP file doesn't have a way to verify the challenge. Actually, your sample PHP file doesn't do anything at all.

When Facebook posts to your callback, your callback needs to match the challenge.

Please re-read https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/webhooks/v2.5

Comment: Yes, you are right. I have added the code for matching the challenge and problem resolved. Thanks for help :)